# SSH directly into MySQL server

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, ssh

i got a remote webserver running with a mysql database.
Right now im using SSH to do any serverside management, and i access the MySQL often. I wondered if its possible for me to make a script that would ssh into the server and if run with "-sql" (subject to change) on the command line it would instead go into mysql.

What i made so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "-l" ]; then
    ssh user@192.168.0.101 //local address for privacy;
    mysql -u root -p;
else
    ssh user@192.168.0.101
fi
```

This results in an SSH session and when it ends my computer will try and create a mysql connection on the local machine.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "-l" ]; then
    ssh user@192.168.0.101 'mysql -u root -p';
else
    ssh user@192.168.0.101
fi
```

This results in a password request and then nothing. I'm assuming its because using ssh with a command expects a response and then shuts down the connection.

Is there any way to do this, i realise that it's not of any significant importance, but it is fun to play around with

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The `mysql` command only executes interactively if it's input is a terminal. When you run `ssh` with a command argument, it doesn't normally allocate a pseudo-tty on the server. So `mysql` just processes its standard input without displaying a prompt.

Use the `-t` option to force this:

```
ssh -t user@192.168.0.101 'mysql -u root -p'
```

Answer (score 3):

One option you might want to consider for solving this kind of access problem is through the use of the tunneling facility in ssh:

```
ssh -l user -L 33306:192.168.0.101:3306 192.168.0.101
```

or maybe

```
ssh -l user -L 33306:127.0.0.1:3306 192.168.0.101
```

This creates a port on your local machine (33306) which tunnels to the mysql port (3306) on the remote machine.

Then on your local machine you run a local copy of mysql:

```
mysql --port=33306 -u root -p
```

which should connect through the tunneled port to your database.

Comment: Tunnelling is the way to go here because you're not restricted to using the command-line client. You can connect applications of any sort as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. Feed mysql password with the command. So you don't have to enter the password.

```
ssh user@192.168.0.101 'mysql --user="root" --password="password" --database="database" --execute="My Query;"'
```

Also I suggest you to set keybased ssh authentication. Hence you can also avoid typing ssh password every time.